# Mock private field being initialized by OSGI Felix container

Tags: java, mockito, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I'm trying to mock a private field in my class which is being initialized by OSGI container in which my app is running. I'm putting a sample code for reference, any clue on this please:

```
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.*
@Component (name = "MyServiceImpl ", ds = true, immediate = true)
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl extends MyBasee implements MyService {

    @Reference (name = "MyOtherService", bind = "bind", unbind = "unbind", policy = ReferencePolicy.STATIC)
    private MyOtherService myServiceRegistryConsumer;
}
```

Here I'm trying to mock private field `MyOtherService myServiceRegistryConsumer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Mockito you can mock and inject fields using the `@InjectMocks`annotation.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AppTest {

    @Mock
    private MyOtherService myServiceRegistryConsumer;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyServiceImpl myServiceImpl;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        // e.g. define behavior for the injected field
        when(myServiceRegistryConsumer.methodA()).thenReturn(/* mocked return value */);
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question for more clarity . This way I wont be having any control over private field myServiceRegistryConsumer. I don't want to inject/mock MyServiceImpl but MyOtherService object, which is being instantiated by container.

Comment: @Arun `myServiceImpl` is not a mock here. Mockito only mocks `myServiceRegistryConsumer` and injects it into the instance. In a test method you still have full control over the mock and you're able to define behavior for it.

Comment: Yes, working exactly the way you explained. Thanks a lot :)