# Powermock and Mockito - mock is ignored

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I'm trying to inject a child mock to my Main.class, and it doesn't seem to work.
(Using powermock 1.7.0 with junit bundled with dependencies)

The verification says that my mocked object was not interacted. can't figure out why.

This is my Main.class:

```
public class Main {
  private Child child;

  public Main(){    }

  public void setChild(Child child){
    this.child = child;
  }

  public void play(){
    child = new Child();
    child.setNumber(50);
    System.out.println(child.getNumber());
  }
}
```

This is my Child.class :

```
public class Child {

  private int number;

  public void setNumber(int number){
      this.number = number;
  }

  public int getNumber(){
      return number;
  }
}
```

And this is my Test.class:

```
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Child.class, Main.class})
public class MainTest {
    private Child child;
    private Main main;

    @Test
    public void testMain(){
        main = new Main();
        main.play();
        Mockito.verify(child).getNumber();
    }

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        child = mock(Child.class);
        when(child.getNumber()).thenReturn(10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mock you create in your test is never actually used, because the Main object creates a new Child object each time you call *play()* on it.

What you want is a way to tell the production code to use the mocked child instance, e.g. by means of a setter.

**Main**

```
public void play(){
    // child = new Child(); // do not create a new instance each time
    child.setNumber(50);
    System.out.println(child.getNumber());
}
```

**MainTest**

```
@Test
public void testMain(){
    main = new Main();
    main.setChild(child); // tell it to use the mock
    main.play(); 
    Mockito.verify(child).getNumber();
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. but let's assume that Main.class is a 3rd party class, which does not have a setter for the Child property. so how can I inject it?
In my actual case, the child property is @Autowired

Comment: If you can't alter Main at all, meaning its _play()_ method always creates a new instance, there's nothing you can do. However, if it does not create a new child each time and doesn't have a setter, you can try using `@InjectMocks` to inject mocks into fields https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839906/mock-private-field-being-initialized-by-osgi-felix-container/44840159#44840159

Comment: I tried to do it before, and it didn't work just because I did it this way:
`@InjectMocks
private Main main;`

and then in the
testMain()
I did the initializing:
`main = new Main();`

The only way it works, is if you initialize the member right under the @InjectMocks annotation.

Is there any code that can replace the use of these annotations?
something like: injectMocks(main, child); ?

Comment: @YuvalBarness to my knowledge there's no method available to inject mocks